# Strange duplicate behavior from GROUP_CONCAT of two LEFT JOINs of GROUP_BYs

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join, group-concat

[Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e171298affc2b90d99e0024be780fc76) is all my tables' structure and the query *(please focus on the **last** query, appended below)*. As you see in the fiddle, here is the **current output:**

```
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+
| user_id | user_name | score | reputation | top_two_tags |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+
| 1       | Jack      | 0     | 18         | css,mysql    |
| 4       | James     | 1     | 5          | html         |
| 2       | Peter     | 0     | 0          | null         |
| 3       | Ali       | 0     | 0          | null         |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+
```

It's correct and all fine.

---

Now I have one more existence named "category". Each post can has only one category. And I also want to get top two categories for each user. And [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ffeac0c84b9ef9f9304c227f56f4e155) is my new query. As you see in the result, some duplicates happened:

```
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| user_id | user_name | score | reputation | top_two_tags |   top_two_categories   |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| 1       | Jack      | 0     | 18         | css,css      | technology,technology  |
| 4       | James     | 1     | 5          | html         | political              |
| 2       | Peter     | 0     | 0          | null         | null                   |
| 3       | Ali       | 0     | 0          | null         | null                   |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

See? `css,css`, `technology, technology`. Why these are duplicate? I've just added one more `LEFT JOIN` for `categories`, exactly like `tags`. But it doesn't work as expected and even affects on the tags either.

---

Anyway, this is **the expected result:**

```
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| user_id | user_name | score | reputation | top_two_tags |        category        |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| 1       | Jack      | 0     | 18         | css,mysql    | technology,social      |
| 4       | James     | 1     | 5          | html         | political              |
| 2       | Peter     | 0     | 0          | null         | null                   |
| 3       | Ali       | 0     | 0          | null         | null                   |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

Does anybody know how can I achieve that?

---

```
CREATE TABLE users(id integer PRIMARY KEY, user_name varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE tags(id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, tag varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE reputations(
    id  integer PRIMARY KEY, 
    post_id  integer /* REFERENCES posts(id) */, 
    user_id integer REFERENCES users(id), 
    score integer, 
    reputation integer, 
    date_time integer);
CREATE TABLE post_tag(
    post_id integer /* REFERENCES posts(id) */, 
    tag_id integer REFERENCES tags(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id));
CREATE TABLE categories(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, category varchar(10) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE post_category(
    post_id INTEGER NOT NULL /* REFERENCES posts(id) */, 
    category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES categories(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(post_id, category_id)) ;

SELECT
    q1.user_id, q1.user_name, q1.score, q1.reputation, 
    substring_index(group_concat(q2.tag  ORDER BY q2.tag_reputation DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 2) AS top_two_tags,
    substring_index(group_concat(q3.category  ORDER BY q3.category_reputation DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 2) AS category
FROM
    (SELECT 
        u.id AS user_Id, 
        u.user_name,
        coalesce(sum(r.score), 0) as score,
        coalesce(sum(r.reputation), 0) as reputation
    FROM 
        users u
        LEFT JOIN reputations r 
            ON    r.user_id = u.id 
              AND r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
    GROUP BY 
        u.id, u.user_name
    ) AS q1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        r.user_id AS user_id, t.tag, sum(r.reputation) AS tag_reputation
    FROM
        reputations r 
        JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.post_id = r.post_id
        JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
    WHERE
        r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
    GROUP BY
        user_id, t.tag
    ) AS q2
    ON q2.user_id = q1.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        r.user_id AS user_id, c.category, sum(r.reputation) AS category_reputation
    FROM
        reputations r 
        JOIN post_category ct ON ct.post_id = r.post_id
        JOIN categories c ON c.id = ct.category_id
    WHERE
        r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
    GROUP BY
        user_id, c.category
    ) AS q3
    ON q3.user_id = q1.user_id 
GROUP BY
    q1.user_id, q1.user_name, q1.score, q1.reputation
ORDER BY
    q1.reputation DESC, q1.score DESC ;
```

Comment: Try: `... group_concat(distinct q2.tag ...` and `... group_concat(distinct q3.category ...`.

Comment: @wchiquito Yes using `distinct` removes duplicates and works as expected. But I think I have to write the query the other way. Because my current query seems to has lots of waste processing. Isn't it true?

Comment: Well done for providing a fiddle - and an expected result

Comment: @Strawberry ha ha ha .. eventually I followed what you constantly were saying to me.

Comment: We can expect that the code you have added to the bottom of your old query to get the new is joining not on a unique set of fields (eg PK). PS Please find a query that just does your last step before you integrate. You can use a CTE or VIEW. (The *minimal* in mcve.) Also, to make your fine post finer, please include relevant code (DDL & queries) as text inline, as you did your tables.

Comment: @philipxy Yeah I guess the second `LEFT JOIN` should be on the result of the first `LEFT JOIN`. Not on the same level.

Comment: OK - I still don't really understand how posts and users and tags are related

Comment: @Strawberry Each post own at least one tag and exactly one category. Now I want to get a list of users and their repo in a specific range, plus their tags and categories they been activate in it. Something like [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users)

Comment: But what do posts have to do with users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query is of the form:

```
q1 -- PK user_id
LEFT JOIN (...
    GROUP BY user_id, t.tag
) AS q2
ON q2.user_id = q1.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (...
    GROUP BY user_id, c.category
) AS q3
ON q3.user_id = q1.user_id
GROUP BY -- group_concats
```

The inner GROUP BYs result in `(user_id, t.tag)` & `(user_id, c.category)` being keys/UNIQUEs. Other than that I won't address those GROUP BYs.

**TL;DR** When you join (q1 JOIN q2) to q3 it is not on a key/UNIQUE of one of them so for each user_id you get a row for every possible combination of tag & category. So the final GROUP BY inputs duplicates per (user_id, tag) & per (user_id, category) and inappropriately GROUP_CONCATs duplicate tags & categories per user_id. Correct would be (q1 JOIN q2 GROUP BY) JOIN (q1 JOIN q3 GROUP BY) in which all joins are on common key/UNIQUE `(user_id)` & there is no spurious aggregation. Although sometimes you can undo such spurious aggregation.

A correct symmetrical INNER JOIN approach: LEFT JOIN q1 & q2--1:many--then GROUP BY & GROUP_CONCAT (which is what your first query did); then separately similarly LEFT JOIN q1 & q3--1:many--then GROUP BY & GROUP_CONCAT; then INNER JOIN the two results ON user_id--1:1.

A correct symmetrical scalar subquery approach: SELECT the GROUP_CONCATs from q1 as [scalar subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29879552/340409) each with a GROUP BY.

A correct cumulative LEFT JOIN approach: LEFT JOIN q1 & q2--1:many--then GROUP BY & GROUP_CONCAT; then LEFT JOIN that & q3--1:many--then GROUP BY & GROUP_CONCAT.

A correct approach like your 2nd query: You first LEFT JOIN q1 & q2--1:many. Then you LEFT JOIN that & q3--many:1:many. It gives a row for every possible combination of a tag & a category that appear with a user_id. Then after you GROUP BY you GROUP_CONCAT--over duplicate (user_id, tag) pairs and duplicate (user_id, category) pairs. That is why you have duplicate list elements. But adding DISTINCT to GROUP_CONCAT gives a correct result. (Per [wchiquito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316440/wchiquito)'s comment.)

Which you prefer is as usual an engineering tradeoff to be informed by query plans & timings, per actual data/usage/statistics. input & stats for expected amount of duplication), timing of actual queries, etc. One issue is whether the extra rows of the many:1:many JOIN approach offset its saving of a GROUP BY.

```
-- cumulative LEFT JOIN approach
SELECT
   q1.user_id, q1.user_name, q1.score, q1.reputation,
    top_two_tags,
    substring_index(group_concat(q3.category  ORDER BY q3.category_reputation DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 2) AS category
FROM
    -- your 1st query (less ORDER BY) AS q1
    (SELECT
        q1.user_id, q1.user_name, q1.score, q1.reputation, 
        substring_index(group_concat(q2.tag  ORDER BY q2.tag_reputation DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 2) AS top_two_tags
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            u.id AS user_Id, 
            u.user_name,
            coalesce(sum(r.score), 0) as score,
            coalesce(sum(r.reputation), 0) as reputation
        FROM 
            users u
            LEFT JOIN reputations r 
                ON    r.user_id = u.id 
                  AND r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
        GROUP BY 
            u.id, u.user_name
        ) AS q1
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            r.user_id AS user_id, t.tag, sum(r.reputation) AS tag_reputation
        FROM
            reputations r 
            JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.post_id = r.post_id
            JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
        WHERE
            r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
        GROUP BY
            user_id, t.tag
        ) AS q2
        ON q2.user_id = q1.user_id 
        GROUP BY
            q1.user_id, q1.user_name, q1.score, q1.reputation
    ) AS q1
    -- finish like your 2nd query
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        r.user_id AS user_id, c.category, sum(r.reputation) AS category_reputation
    FROM
        reputations r 
        JOIN post_category ct ON ct.post_id = r.post_id
        JOIN categories c ON c.id = ct.category_id
    WHERE
        r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
    GROUP BY
        user_id, c.category
    ) AS q3
    ON q3.user_id = q1.user_id 
GROUP BY
    q1.user_id, q1.user_name, q1.score, q1.reputation
ORDER BY
    q1.reputation DESC, q1.score DESC ;
```

Comment: Ok, just as a consult, which one is your recommendation? Using `DISTINCT`? Using `LEFT JOIN` *(like your answer)*? Using *Subquery* ?

Comment: There is no general principle by which to decide here. I said, it's a tradeoff *you must measure in your exact circumstances* (including importantly your expectations & optimizer), as always for engineering "best" (a chimera). (The plans for the distinct & cumulative queries seem close; but the data & statistics are toy. I would expect an optimizer to implement the subselect query close to the cumulative or inner join, because there are obvious simple transformations between them. I'm more suspicious of all the repetition in your queries, but I wanted to address the issues around the joins.)

Comment: PS I'm sure there's a lot to be got at dba.stackexchange.com. But arrive *prepared*.