# Mysql query - Showing a second taxonomy for a product stopped me

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, case, pivot-table

I am in the situation where I need of the following information:

1. ID       (posts.ID)
2. TITLE    (posts.title)
3. SKU      (postmeta.metakey = ‘_sku’) --> value stored in (postmeta.metavalue)
4. PRICE    (postmeta.metakey= ‘regular_price’) -> value stored in (postmeta.metavalue)
5. BRAND    (terms.name WHERE term_taxonomy_term.taxonomy=‘product_cat’)
6. CATEGORY (terms.name WHERE term_taxonomy_term.taxonomy=‘brand’)

`SKU` and `PRICE` belongs to the same column "postemeta.metakey" which related values are in the "postemeta.metavalue".

`BRAND` and `CATEGORY` belongs to the same column "terms.name" but they have different taxonomies defined in "term_taxonomy.taxonomy" and are ('product_brand' and 'product_cat').

Developing the query below I was able to collect all the information except for one that is the `BRAND` (terms.name).

```
   SELECT p.ID
          , MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sku' 
                     THEN pm1.meta_value 
                     ELSE NULL END) AS sku
          , p.post_title
          , t.name AS product_category
          , MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' 
                     THEN pm1.meta_value 
                     ELSE NULL END) AS price
     FROM mg_posts p 
LEFT JOIN mg_postmeta AS pm1 
       ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN mg_term_relationships AS tr 
       ON tr.object_id = p.ID
     JOIN mg_term_taxonomy AS tt 
       ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
     JOIN mg_terms AS t 
       ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
    WHERE p.post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation') 
    GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title
```

Any help to fix this issue??

Comment: What problem are you having with brand? [mcve] please. 'belongs to the same column "postemeta.metakey" which related values are in the "postemeta.metavalue"&nbsp;' is not clear. Ditto for your descriptions 5 & 6. (Although I can figure out what would be clear from the code. Please do so too. Then use that instead.) PS Shouldn't 5 say "=‘product_brand'" & 6 say "=‘product_cat’"? And "mg_taxonomy_term"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45250646/3404097.  (Although you are using a different aggregate.) (See my answer there.)

Answer (score 0):

Philipxy, I think it's better to proceed step by step, being focused on the issue.

Category and Brand are stored both in the same way:

```
TERMS            TERM_TAXONOMY          TERM_RELATIONSHIP          PRODUCT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
term_id  ---->   term_id                product_id      --->   product_id
name             †erm_taxonomy_id   --> term_taxonomy_id
                 taxonomy
```

Brand and Category are identified in term.taxonomy.taxonomy as 'product_brand' and 'product_cat' and their name is stored in terms.term_id.

Now the task is to get result in separated column

```
|ProductID |   Brand    |     Category      |
---------------------------------------------
| 001      |    Levis   |     Men Jeans     |
```

After solving this I keep to develop the matter.

Answer (score 0):

To whom can be interested I found the final solution to get the information I needed.

```
SELECT 
     p.id, 
     p.post_title, 
     p.post_status,
     MAX(CASE WHEN t.taxonomy = 'product_cat' then tr.name ELSE NULL END) as category,
     MAX(CASE WHEN t.taxonomy = 'product_brand' then tr.name ELSE NULL END) as brand,
     MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_sku' then pm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sku,
     MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_price' then pm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price
     FROM mg_posts as p
     LEFT JOIN mg_term_relationships as r ON r.object_id=p.id
     JOIN mg_term_taxonomy as t ON t.term_taxonomy_id=r.term_taxonomy_id
     JOIN mg_terms as tr ON tr.term_id=t.term_id
     JOIN mg_postmeta pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
     WHERE P.post_type='product' 
     GROUP BY P.ID
```

Hope it can helps!