# LEFT JOIN in Query returning more records than desired

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on an MS ACCESS query which should pull all available data from one main table (specified by FROM) and then joining three additional tables via LEFT JOIN. My issue is that the query is returning more records because of a one to many relationship.

Is there any way I can return only ONE record per line in the main table? Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

```
    SELECT tbl_Item_PO.Item, 
    tbl_ItemSKUType.SKU, 
    tbl_Item_PO.[EX-FACTORY DATE], 
    tbl_Item_PO.[QTY PER SHIPMENT],
    IIf(tbl_Item_PO.Item=Posted_Inv_Tran.Item And tbl_Item_PO.Whse=Posted_Inv_Tran.Whse And tbl_Item_PO.[ITR#]=Posted_Inv_Tran.[TRN Number],0,tbl_Item_PO.[QTY PER SHIPMENT]) AS QTY, 
    tbl_Item_PO.WHSE, tbl_WhseRegion.Region
    FROM ((tbl_Item_PO 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ItemSKUType ON tbl_Item_PO.item = tbl_ItemSKUType.Item) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_WhseRegion ON tbl_Item_PO.WHSE = tbl_WhseRegion.Whse) 
    LEFT JOIN Posted_Inv_Tran ON (tbl_Item_PO.[ITR#] = Posted_Inv_Tran.[TRN Number]) AND (tbl_Item_PO.Whse = Posted_Inv_Tran.Whse) AND (tbl_Item_PO.Item = Posted_Inv_Tran.Item);
```

I've also tried creating sub-queries within the join statements that return only ONE record but I cannot get that to work either:

```
    SELECT po.Item, 
    ist.SKU, 
    po.[EX-FACTORY DATE], 
    po.[QTY PER SHIPMENT],
    IIf(po.Item=itr.Item And po.Whse=itr.Whse And po.[ITR#]=itr.[TRN Number],0,po.[QTY PER SHIPMENT]) AS QTY, 
    po.WHSE, 
    wh.Region
    FROM ((tbl_Item_PO po
    LEFT JOIN (select top 1 * from tbl_ItemSKUType
             RIGHT JOIN tbl_Item_PO on tbl_ItemSKUType.Item = tbl_Item_PO.item
             WHERE tbl_Item_PO.Item = tbl_ItemSKUType.Item) 
             ist ON po.item = ist.Item)
    LEFT JOIN (select top 1 * from tbl_WhseRegion
             RIGHT JOIN tbl_Item_PO on tbl_WhseRegion.Whse = tbl_Item_PO.Whse
             WHERE tbl_Item_PO.whse = tbl_WhseRegion.Whse) 
             wh ON po.Whse = wh.Whse)
    LEFT JOIN (select top 1 * from Posted_Inv_Tran
            RIGHT JOIN tbl_Item_PO on Posted_Inv_Tran.[TRN Number] = tbl_Item_PO.[ITR#] AND Posted_Inv_Tran.Whse = tbl_Item_PO.Whse AND Posted_Inv_Tran.Item = tbl_Item_PO.Item
            WHERE (tbl_Item_PO.[ITR#] = Posted_Inv_Tran.[TRN Number]) AND (tbl_Item_PO.Whse = Posted_Inv_Tran.Whse) AND (tbl_Item_PO.Item = Posted_Inv_Tran.Item)) 
            it ON (po.[ITR#] = it.[TRN Number]) AND (po.Whse = it.Whse) AND (po.Item = it.Item);
```

Comment: You probably don't want a triple left join, you probably want the inner join of two left joins. [Because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252750/3404097) you are not always left joining on the key to the leftmost table equal to a FK to it. Think: left join returns what inner join returns plus unmatched rows extended by nulls. Inner join not on key to FK can introduce multiple rows. But you need to give contraints & preferably example data to confirm before I can answer. In fact for code always give a [mcve] or a question is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with a `group by` clause. Make sure to list all fields in that clause which identify a line, and that all other expressions/fields you have in the `select` clause are aggregated with some aggregation function, like `Min()`.

NB: Your `IIf` condition does not need to check all those fields, just one is enough: when one matches, all will match:

```
SELECT  tbl_Item_PO.Item, 
        Min(tbl_ItemSKUType.SKU) AS SKU, 
        tbl_Item_PO.[EX-FACTORY DATE], 
        tbl_Item_PO.[QTY PER SHIPMENT],
        Min(IIf(tbl_Item_PO.Item=Posted_Inv_Tran.Item, 0,  
                                  tbl_Item_PO.[QTY PER SHIPMENT])) AS QTY, 
        tbl_Item_PO.WHSE,
        Min(tbl_WhseRegion.Region) AS Region
FROM    ((tbl_Item_PO 
LEFT JOIN tbl_ItemSKUType 
        ON tbl_Item_PO.item = tbl_ItemSKUType.Item) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_WhseRegion 
        ON tbl_Item_PO.WHSE = tbl_WhseRegion.Whse) 
LEFT JOIN Posted_Inv_Tran 
        ON (tbl_Item_PO.[ITR#] = Posted_Inv_Tran.[TRN Number]) 
        AND (tbl_Item_PO.Whse = Posted_Inv_Tran.Whse) 
        AND (tbl_Item_PO.Item = Posted_Inv_Tran.Item)
GROUP BY tbl_Item_PO.Item, 
        tbl_Item_PO.[EX-FACTORY DATE], 
        tbl_Item_PO.[QTY PER SHIPMENT],
        tbl_Item_PO.WHSE;
```

Comment: Thank you! This may work. My only concern would be that the QTY (quantity) values will be blown up for records with multiple matches in the joined tables. Will the MIN function take care of that?

Comment: `Min` will just take one value, the least one among the many that fit the join. But since the value will in practice be just the same repeated value when you have multiple join matches, this just means: "pick that value". It *would* blow up if you would use `Sum` instead of `Min`.