# Wrong result in query with left join

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, left-join

For my project I have a SQLite DB like the following:

https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5aba37c986797mugjf9muddm

And I'm trying to obtain information about this with the query:

```
select 
     a.id_interno, 
     a.id_esterno, 
     count(b.id_ingrediente), 
     count(c.id_utente) 
from 
     lista_spesa a 
          left join elemento_lista_spesa b on b.id_lista_spesa = a.id_interno 
          left join utente_lista_spesa c on c.id_lista_spesa = a.id_interno 
group by 
    b.id_lista_spesa, c.id_lista_spesa;
```

But I obtain for the counts

```
ID_INTERNO|ID_ESTERNO|count(b.id_ingrediente)|count(c.id_utente)
1|-1|2|2
```

but I expect the following result:

```
ID_INTERNO|ID_ESTERNO|count(b.id_ingrediente)|count(c.id_utente)
1|-1|1|2
```

Why I have this wrong result? How can I fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange duplicate behavior from GROUP\_CONCAT of two LEFT JOINs of GROUP\_BYs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250646/strange-duplicate-behavior-from-group-concat-of-two-left-joins-of-group-bys)

Comment: This is a faq: You need a join of two separate aggregations of left joins on keys. (Or equivalent.) You might have found an answer if you actually clearly stated your question/problem/goal. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. Also you should have looked at the result of your first left join and seen if it was what you expected--part of making a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Because you are joining the tables together, you have duplicate values. Try to add a distinct into the count functions:

```
select a.id_interno,
       a.id_esterno,
       count(DISTINCT b.id_ingrediente),
       count(DISTINCT c.id_utente) 
  from lista_spesa a
  left join elemento_lista_spesa b
    on b.id_lista_spesa = a.id_interno
  left join utente_lista_spesa c
    on c.id_lista_spesa = a.id_interno
 group by b.id_lista_spesa, c.id_lista_spesa;
```

Comment: I know this solution but i thinked that group by were sufficient...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
select a.id_interno, a.id_esterno, (select count(id_ingrediente) from elemento_lista_spesa) as cuentab, (select count(id_utente) from utente_lista_spesa) as cuentac
from lista_spesa a left join elemento_lista_spesa b on b.id_lista_spesa = a.id_interno 
left join utente_lista_spesa c on c.id_lista_spesa = a.id_interno
group by b.id_lista_spesa, c.id_lista_spesa;
```

the result is:

```
1, -1, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you don't need to use Group by for this query. Just use `DISTINCT` inside your `count()` function

**OPTION 1**

```
 SELECT 
    lista_spesa.id_interno, 
    lista_spesa.id_esterno,
    count(DISTINCT elemento_lista_spesa.id_ingrediente), 
    count(DISTINCT utente_lista_spesa.id_utente) 
FROM
    lista_spesa
        left join elemento_lista_spesa on elemento_lista_spesa.id_lista_spesa  = lista_spesa.id_interno
        left join utente_lista_spesa on utente_lista_spesa.id_lista_spesa = lista_spesa.id_interno
```

**OPTION 2**

```
SELECT 
    lista_spesa.id_interno, 
    lista_spesa.id_esterno,
    (SELECT count(elemento_lista_spesa.id_ingrediente) FROM elemento_lista_spesa WHERE elemento_lista_spesa.id_lista_spesa  = lista_spesa.id_interno) AS COUNT1, 
    (SELECT count(utente_lista_spesa.id_utente) FROM utente_lista_spesa WHERE utente_lista_spesa.id_lista_spesa = lista_spesa.id_interno) AS COUNT2
FROM
    lista_spesa
```

Comment: the first solution is not good in case when lista_spesa has more records,  in that case the query returns only one record