# Join with sub query vs Join to table - why is join to table incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery, left-join

I have 2 queries;

- 1 with sub query join - this is pulling everything back correctly
- 1 with a join - this is pulling back an incorrect calculation in the GrossAnnualDebit, and overall is much lower than the GrossAnnualDebit figure from the sub query joins.

```
SELECT prty_id AS PropertyID, 
       ISNULL(SUM(tr.grs_val_trans), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(voi.grs_valtrs), 0) AS GrossAnnualDebit
FROM qlfdat..hgmprty1 p1
     LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT prty_ref, 
           SUM(grs_val_trans) AS grs_val_trans
    FROM qlfdat..hratrans
    WHERE trans_ppyy BETWEEN 201805 AND 201904
          AND trans_type = 'D'
    GROUP BY prty_ref
) AS tr ON tr.prty_ref = p1.prty_id
     LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT prty_ref, 
           SUM(grs_valtrs) AS grs_valtrs
    FROM qlfdat..hraptvtt
    WHERE trans_ppyy BETWEEN 201805 AND 201904
    GROUP BY prty_ref
) AS voi ON voi.prty_ref = p1.prty_id
GROUP BY prty_id;
```

```
SELECT prty_id AS PropertyID, 
       ISNULL(SUM(tr.grs_val_trans), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(voi.grs_valtrs), 0) AS GrossAnnualDebit
FROM qlfdat..hgmprty1 p1
     LEFT JOIN qlfdat..hratrans AS tr ON tr.prty_ref = p1.prty_id
                                         AND tr.trans_type = 'D'
                                         AND tr.trans_ppyy BETWEEN 201805 AND 201904
     LEFT JOIN qlfdat..hraptvtt AS voi ON voi.prty_ref = p1.prty_id
                                          AND voi.trans_ppyy BETWEEN 201805 AND 201904
                                  AND voi.trans_ppyy = tr.trans_ppyy
GROUP BY prty_id;
```

Comment: We can't see your data, or run your queries, so this is very hard to even begin to answer on. Note, however, that you have a `GROUP BY` and `SUM` in the subqueries, however, the only aggregation in your second query is the once. That changes the query, so those 2 queries are not the same.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu - I appreciate they're not the same, however they're both pulling back very similar data. I also appreciate that you cannot see the data. Is there anyway I can represent data onto Stackoverflow?

Comment: I believe the data difference stems from the non-equivalence of putting the same condition in the `ON` and `WHERE` parts of a `LEFT JOIN`. Not sure how to formulate an example, though.

Comment: Yes @WRD299, DDL and DML statements are the best way, as we can run them on our local instance.

Comment: This seems likely to be a common error where people want the join of some aggregations (each possibly involving joining) but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating. [Strange duplicate behavior from GROUP_CONCAT of two LEFT JOINs of GROUP_BYs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252750/3404097) PS Of course your queries don't agree. What are we supposed to say?--Find out how the operators act? If you think they should be the same then explain why & show the first step you get something you don't expect so we can tell you where your misunderstandings are.

Comment: Thank you @philipxy I will do this for future questions :)

Answer (score 1):

I could tell exactly what's the issue without sample code, but a difference I could see is on second query, your `voi`  table is no longer `left join with p1` table, you left join it with `tr` table, that might cause your issue.

Comment: Thank you, After joining this with a separate join this worked :)