# sum() does not work properly in MySQL query with multiple joins (group by does not work as expected)

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I have tables Orders, Networks and Users and I need to get **total orders count** and **total sum for orders** for every user, and users count in the same network that every user have.

**SQLFiddle with sample data:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcbeea/1

users.userid, orders.id - unique primary keys.

In this example check user #24 row: values for **total_orders**,    **total_revenue**, **network_users** are not correct.

**Current results for user #24:** total_orders: 6, total_revenue: 350, network_users: 6.

**Expected results for user #24:** total_orders: 3, total_revenue: 175, network_users: 2.

This is SQL request:

```
SELECT u.*,
   count(o.id) AS total_orders,
   sum(o.total) AS total_revenue,
   count(un.userid) as network_users /* Users count in same network */
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.userid=u.userid
LEFT JOIN users am ON u.ownerid = am.userid
LEFT JOIN users bdr ON u.bdrid = bdr.userid
LEFT JOIN networks n ON u.networkid = n.networkid
LEFT JOIN users un ON n.networkid=un.networkid
GROUP BY u.userid
ORDER BY u.userid DESC;
```

ISSUE 1:
**total_orders** and **total_revenue** here return incorrect values (more than it should, looks like it summed few times because of networks table join).

I can fix total_orders by adding distinct -  **count(distinct(o.id)) AS total_orders**, however this does not work for sum because I can't set to sum total only by disctinct ID's, as I see there is no way to set this in SQL.

You can see issue in SQLFiddle example - user #24 should have total_revenue = 175, however you see it calculated as 350. As I see this happens because two different users associated with the same network (Network #1) that user #24 have.

ISSUE 2: 
**count(un.userid) as network_users** - this does not work properly if I don't add count(disctinct(un.userid)) as network_users. Without 'distinct' this show me overall networks count as I see (and not a overall users count in network with the same networkid as current user have). In SQL example 'network_users' for user id #24 should be 2 (because only 2 users in this network), however I see 6 in results.

**QUESTION:** How to change SQL request to get correct expected mathematically results?

Comment: Please just give your DDL including constraints, MySQL version & the rest of a [mre]. PS This seems likely to be a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. [Strange duplicate behavior from GROUP_CONCAT of two LEFT JOINs of GROUP_BYs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252750/3404097)

Comment: Please put everything needed for your question in the post, as text when possible, plus a link to fiddle. A post should be self-contained. Also--I just asked this--what is the first point where a subexpression doesn't return what you expect? If it's the SELECT then show the output (SELECT *) from all the joins & explain how it is that you think those SUMs are going to return what you want. (They don't. So why are you summing on that join?) What actual join for each total is actually is the right input for it? Why don't you calculate those? PS Please ask 1 specific clear question.

Comment: Put all SQL code needed to run an example in your post. That's a SELECT statement plus declarations plus initializations--everything. Plus a link to a fiddle to show that you ran it. [ask] [help] PS Your description of what your code is supposed to do--part of a [mre]--is not clear. Nobody could write code that they are sure is what you need. We can only guess. (Details re wrong output are not helpful.) PS You seem to rely on PK/UNIQUE/FK constraints that you do not declare or mention. PS Suggest you write a separate subquery for each aggregation & join on a common PK/UNIQUE. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way: Count the `network_users` in a subselect (subquery in the SELECT clause)

```
SELECT u.userid, 
   count(o.id) AS total_orders,
   coalesce(sum(o.total), 0) AS total_revenue,
   (
     SELECT count(*)
     FROM users un     
     WHERE un.networkid = u.networkid
   ) as network_users
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.userid=u.userid
GROUP BY u.userid, u.networkid
ORDER BY u.userid DESC;
```

Result:

```
| userid | total_orders | total_revenue | network_users |
| ------ | ------------ | ------------- | ------------- |
| 40     | 1            | 75            | 1             |
| 37     | 0            | 0             | 2             |
| 33     | 0            | 0             | 1             |
| 24     | 3            | 175           | 2             |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hJFhJUGjdFDzf1jrE9Mro5/0)

Another way: Do "preaggregation" in a derived table (subquery in the FROM clause)

```
SELECT u.userid,
  count(o.id) AS total_orders,
  coalesce(sum(o.total), 0) AS total_revenue,
  u.network_users
FROM (
  SELECT u.userid, count(un.userid) as network_users
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN users un ON un.networkid = u.networkid
  GROUP BY u.userid
) u
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.userid=u.userid
GROUP BY u.userid
ORDER BY u.userid DESC;
```

Result:

```
| userid | network_users | total_orders | total_revenue |
| ------ | ------------- | ------------ | ------------- |
| 40     | 1             | 1            | 75            |
| 37     | 2             | 0            | 0             |
| 33     | 1             | 0            | 0             |
| 24     | 2             | 3            | 175           |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/PgmLKsvknUQsvrpAT2zDe/0)

Some notes:

- Make sure `userid` is UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY in the `users` table. Otherwise you can get an error starting from MySQL 5.7.
- I removed the JOINs with `users am` and `users bdr`. You are not using them in your query. You can put them back, if you want to select anything from them.
- I also removed the JOIN with the `networks` table. You can just join the `users` table with itself using the `networkid` column.
- Use `COALESCE()` for `SUM()` to convert `NULL` to `0`.

Why your query failed to return the expected result? Because you are joining orders from a user with all other users from the same network. Thus the order count and the total amount are multiplied by the number of users in the same network.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. What a reason to use COALESCE()? Order totals for users in table can't be NULL (it's always 0 or more). And I think even if it will be NULL - SUM() should correctly counts for NULL's? (for exam if it will do 5+0+3+NULL+2 - NULL will not be considered as 0 in SUM() automatically in MySQL? Or this will give some error?).

Comment: Remove it, and you will see. What you assume is correct for `COUNT()` but not for `SUM()`. If there are no values for `SUM()` at all (user has no orders), the it will return `NULL`.

Comment: "you are joining orders from a user with all other users from the same network" - but I am using "u" shortname for one join and "un" shortname for another, so users tables should be joined independently, or this is not how JOIN works in MySQL? If I will join the same table (no matter of short names) few times - it will be merged with every join for same table? So I should avoid using JOIN for the same table name in one query and should always divide this to subqueries?

Comment: Joining a table with itself is not the problem. The problem is joining two independent one-to-many relations in the same FROM clause.

Comment: Regarding your first comment - see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum): "If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns NULL" and "If there are no matching rows, SUM() returns NULL." - `SUM()` doestn't convert NULLs to `0`, it's just ignoring them. That's why `SUM(5+0+3+NULL+2)` works - It's equivalent to `SUM(5+0+3+2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way.  When doing a `JOIN`, first all combinations of the rows from the tables are put together into a big temp table (after filtering out any that don't apply).

*Then* aggregates such as `COUNT()` and `SUM()` are computed against this big table.

Usually this is not correct.  And usually the cure is to *first* devise a query that uses the minimum number of tables needed to get the correct sum from the intermediate table.  *Then* do any more `JOINs` you may need.

An alternative (sometimes) is to employ subqueries, either to do the aggregation or to provide the equivalent of `JOINs`.

Sometimes the query will look like this:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT key, COUNT(*), SUM(..) FROM .. GROUP BY .. ) AS a
    JOIN b  ON ...
    JOIN c  ON ...
```

Comment: " And usually the cure is to first devise a query that uses the minimum number of tables needed to get the correct sum from the intermediate table. " - So you suggest to divide this SQL to two separate SQL requests? One to get count() and sum() and other to get all other staff with different joins?

Comment: @Dmitry - Usually no need to have a separate SQL.  I added an example of a "derived table".  Arth has an example, too.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a third option to @Paul's excellent answer

You could do your counts separately, put them together using `UNION ALL`, and then `SUM` these rows

```
  SELECT agg.userid,
         SUM(agg.order_count) AS total_orders,
         SUM(agg.revenue_sum) AS total_revenue,
         SUM(agg.network_user_count) AS network_users

    FROM (

       /** Orders and Revenue */
    SELECT u.userid,
           COUNT(o.id) AS order_count,
           SUM(o.total) AS revenue_sum,
           0 AS network_user_count
      FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.userid=u.userid
  GROUP BY u.userid 

     UNION ALL

       /** Network Users */
    SELECT u.userid, 
           0 AS order_count,
           0 AS revenue_sum,
           COUNT(un.userid) AS network_user_count
      FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN users un 
        ON un.networkid = u.networkid
  GROUP BY u.userid

         ) agg 

GROUP BY agg.userid
ORDER BY agg.userid DESC;
```

The inner query `agg` will give results like

```
| userid | order_count | revenue_sum | network_user_count |
| ------ | ----------- | ----------- | ------------------ |
| …
| 24     | 3           | 175         | 0                  |
| 24     | 0           | 0           | 2                  |
| …
```

And the outer query will then combine these rows with `SUM`s

It's slightly more long winded, but I have used this method in some of our projects

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks Interesting what of 3 methods works more fast (by performance) on large databases..

Comment: @Dmitry You are welcome! I honestly don't know, I think the 3 methods are comparable in terms of work to do, so it will be up to how they interact with any indexes you have in place.. I suggest experimenting with the different options and EXPLAIN SELECT