# In MySQL - 2 LEFT JOINs with FIND_IN_SET show wrong numbers

Tags: mysql, left-join, group, find-in-set

I have one main table and 2 tables that I left-join using "FIND_IN_SET".
When I use a function such as COUNT() or SUM() I get wrong numbers!

They are totally fine when I left-join only one table.

I simplified the tables for the example:

```
CREATE TABLE `Beatles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `Beatles` VALUES (1,'Paul',80),(2,'Ringo',82),(3,'John',81),(4,'George',79);

CREATE TABLE `Nursery` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `Nursery` VALUES (1,'David',2),(2,'Alan',3),(3,'Dan',1);

CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `nurseryIds` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `beatlesIds` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `main` VALUES (1,'party','1,2','3'),(2,'joy','3','2,4'),(3,'good','4','1'),(4,'all together now','1,2,3','1,2,3,4');
```

I ran the query:

```
SELECT M.id, nurseryIds, COUNT(N.id), beatlesIds, COUNT(B.id) FROM guy_test.main M
LEFT JOIN Beatles AS B ON FIND_IN_SET(B.id, M.beatlesIds)
LEFT JOIN Nursery AS N ON FIND_IN_SET(N.id, M.nurseryIds)
GROUP BY M.id
```

The expected result is: (The "count()" counts the number of ids to its left)

| id | nurseryIds | COUNT(N.id) | beatlesIds | COUNT(B.id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 2,4 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1,2,3 | 3 | 1,2,3,4 | 4 |

The actual result:

| id | nurseryIds | COUNT(N.id) | beatlesIds | COUNT(B.id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 2,4 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1,2,3 | 12 | 1,2,3,4 | 12 |

What am I doing wrong? Is it something with the grouping?

Comment: Can I see sample of tableX and tableY?

Comment: It is good to have some confidentiality. But I think some [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be available.

Comment: [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464037/3404097) [Strange duplicate behavior from GROUP_CONCAT of two LEFT JOINs of GROUP_BYs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252750/3404097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 'DISTINCT' keyword before COUNT functions in the field list(or select list). Please try this:

```
SELECT M.id, nurseryIds, COUNT(DISTINCT N.id), beatlesIds, COUNT(DISTINCT B.id) FROM main M
LEFT JOIN Beatles AS B ON FIND_IN_SET(B.id, M.beatlesIds)
LEFT JOIN Nursery AS N ON FIND_IN_SET(N.id, M.nurseryIds)
GROUP BY M.id;
```

If we execute the query:
[image: Click here to see result_set]

Comment: Tried that. Note that on line 3 the COUNT(N.id) gives 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I also need (for the real practice) to use SUM() and I cannot use distinct for that.

Comment: @Guy Arnon Id values in Nursery tables {1,2,3}. On line 3 in Main table, only value {4} appears which is not available in id column in nursery table.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - my bad. But still - this solution is good for the COUNT() function, but not to SUM() - if I want to sum prices for instance I cannot use DISTINCT, because 2 products with same price will be considered one.

Comment: I think, if your aim is to sum prices for instances, You will make the grouping by 2 columns then (unique combination (id column, price column).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 0):

I just sorted my query on this, mine uses JOIN FIND_IN_SET and has SUM, try this:

```
SELECT M.id, nurseryIds, COUNT(N.id), beatlesIds, COUNT(B.id) FROM guy_test.main M
LEFT JOIN Beatles AS B ON FIND_IN_SET(B.id, M.beatlesIds) = 1
LEFT JOIN Nursery AS N ON FIND_IN_SET(N.id, M.nurseryIds) = 1 
GROUP BY M.id
```